# How do I write better template logic with if statements in Django?

Tags: django

How can I write this more efficient in Django templates so it won't be a huge if statement? I want to disable an element to ALL pages in request.path and some exceptions for some pages. This is what I got so far

```
{% if "/create-account/" in request.path or "/lists/" in request.path or "/contact-us/" in request.path or "/news/" in request.path %}
{% else %}
    {% include 'includes/element.html' %}
{% endif %}
```

There must be a better way. **To clarify my needs:**

*Display this element on all pages except X, Y or Z.*

Comment: Hard to say... is there anything those pages have in common that makes it so you don't need to show that element? any logic other than the page url?

Comment: @Sayse: No, nothing other than that I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest way I can think of at the minute is to include a context variable in the context data for those urls that do need to show it

```
# views
{ 'ignore_element': ':)' }

# template
{% if not ignore_element %}
    {% include 'includes/element.html' %}
{% endif %}
```

This would work since its only shown for those that don't include this context value.

Any better solution options would depend on the logic behind why these 4 should be exempt from showing it

Comment: Nice. That looks so way much cleaner! Thank you Sayse for that.

Comment: @lol5433 - No worries! You could use `False` instead of a smiley face... the result would be the same, just less cheery!

Answer (score 1):

I would not use the request object directly.

### views.py

```
def contact_us(request):
    my_context = {
        "hide_element_include": True
    }
    return render_to_response('my_template.html',
                      my_context,
                      context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

### index.html

```
{% if hide_element_include %}
{% else %}
    {% include 'includes/element.html' %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I'm curious of why you're using `render_to_response()` instead of `render()`. However your method looks good to be able to define the logic inside the view. I am too inexperienced to tell the benefits of either in templates or view.

Comment: @lol5433 - From the [docs for `render_to_response`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response) - "This function preceded the introduction of render() and works similarly except that it doesn’t make the request available in the response. It’s not recommended and is likely to be deprecated in the future."

Comment: Well that is good to know! Thanks for the note on render to response.

Answer (score 1):

Try to keep logic *out* of the template in most cases. Assuming this page is being served by a Django controller, all you need to do is add a flag for each URL where you want the element to be hidden.

```
def contact_us(request):
    context = {
        "hide_element": True
    }
    return render('my_template.html', context);
```

template:

```
{% if not hide_element %}
    {% include 'includes/element.html' %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider this easier approach if you have only few pages without "element".

base.html:

```
{% block some_element %}
  {% include 'includes/element.html' %}
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

pages_with_element.html:

```
{% extend 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
  <h1>content here</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

page_without_element.html:

```
 {% extend 'base.html' %}
 {% block some_element %}
 {% endblock %}

 {% block content %}
  <h1>content here</h1>
 {% endblock %}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I can use Django block tag with include tag.

Comment: Yes it's possible, I use it all the time for my toolbars