# Django template logic with views

Tags: python, django

I need help understanding this. I asked this yesterday: [How do I write better template logic with if statements in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35467467/how-do-i-write-better-template-logic-with-if-statements-in-django)

**This is my view now:**

```
def home(request):
    context = {
        "ignore_paths": {
            "/test1/": False,
            "/test2/": False,
            "/test3/": False,
            "/test4/": False,
            "/test5/": False,
            "/test6/": False,
        }
    }
    return render(request, "index.html", context)
```

**index.html:**

```
{% if not ignore_paths %} 
{% include "includes/sidebar.html" %} 
{% endif %}
```

Why do it not work for me?

Comment: How do you know it isn't working?

Comment: The sidebar displays on the pages that are set to be ignored. @jpaugh

Comment: That isn't how I intended my answer to be applied... you need to include 'ignored_paths' in the context data of every view you want ignored

Answer (score 3):

Your `ignore_paths` variable is a dictionary.  It will always be `True` unless the dictionary is empty, so `{% if not ignore_paths %}` will always evaluate to `False`.  What you want is to check each of the your paths in `ignore_paths` and if any of them are `True` to not show template if I'm reading your other post correctly.

I'd make `ignore_paths` a list or set of the paths you don't want to show the sidebar to like:

`'ignore_paths': {'/test1/', '/test2/', '/test3/', '/test4/', '/test5/', '/test6/'}`

then use [any](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) to check if any of the paths are in the `request.path`:

`hide_sidebar = any(path in request.path for path in ignore_paths)`

then in your view:

`{% if not hide_sidebar %} 
{% include "includes/sidebar.html" %} 
{% endif %}`

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work because you weren't using it in the way it was intended....

Your original question was asking how to exclude that side bar in all templates except for a couple.

The way its intended to work is you include the `"ignore_paths"` key in the context of those views that *do not* need to show it, the value isn't important as long as it equates to true.

i.e I used the `":)"` string since a string with any value will equal true.

The template then does the hard work, since the "ignore_paths" key is missing in the context of those views that *do* need to show it it will evaluate the if statement successfully and enter it to include the sidebar, see the breakdown of the logic involved here.

```
ignore_paths is included                        ignore_paths isn't included
{% if not ignore_paths %}                       {% if not ignore_paths %} 
{% if not True %}                               {% if not False %}
{% if False %}                                  {% if True %}
Doesn't enter if                                Does enter if statement
```